# When I tab over in the editor side of LaTeX, it displays a visible arrow tab there. Is there any way I can fix this?

Tags: texstudio

[image]

I've tried messing around with Options > Configure TeXstudio, but I can't get the arrow to go away or blend into the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn off the `Show Whitespace` option of the TeXstudio in the following way:

> Options
>
> Configure TeXstudio
>
> ☑ Show Advanced Options (Must be checked!)
>
> Adv. Editor
>
> ☐ Show Whitespace (Remove the check mark!)

Comment: You're an absolute godsend, that was driving me crazy.